# Ajax delete product from cart in magento

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

I have been working with magento cart pro extension. For ajax add to cart functionality, i have followed this following link [Excellance Magento Blog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax)

Its working Fine.But i have searched a lot regarding ajax delete item from cart, But google returns me always with 3rd party extension. I can't find tutorial for delete product from cart. So i thought, to take a referrance from one of free 3rd party extension which have an both add to cart and delete from cart functionality. I found this following extension which have above both function and also working rock. [Ajax cart pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-add-to-cart-1.html) .

I have checked this extension coding part. But I'm really confused, I can't find which code doing delete functionality. They have overwrite only deleteAction in controller file only, I think.I can't understand even what i'm doing.I just need the guidance to add ajax delete functionality.

If anybody have an idea or found any tutorial of this, please share with me your thoughts friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diving into an Ajaxcart extension, in the controller's action, we could find (yeah, you were right!), the following line is actually removing an item:

**$this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)->save();**

```
public function deleteAction() {
    $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($id) {
        try {
            $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
                    ->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxcart/response');
            $_response->setError(true);
            $_response->setMessage($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
            $_response->send();

            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

    $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxcart/response');

    $_response->setMessage($this->__('Item was removed.'));

    //append updated blocks
    $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('ajaxcart');
    $this->loadLayout();

    $_response->addUpdatedBlocks($_response);

    $_response->send();
}
```

So answering you question "which code doing the delete", it's definitely therein;)

And to understand a whole process, you should have in mind these points:

- ***ajaxcart.js*** - they're overriding Magento's setLocation function and then doing a ajax call(in ajaxCartSubmit method):

  ```
  var oldSetLocation = setLocation;
  var setLocation = (function() {
      return function(url){
         if( url.search('checkout/cart/add') != -1 ) {
              //its simple/group/downloadable product
              ajaxcart.ajaxCartSubmit(url);
  ```
- to render ***a button*** use url helper, like this:

  ```
  <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart"
      onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, $additional = array('qty' => 1));?>')">
   +
  </button>
  ```
- ***updateBlocks.*** There are an Observer and ***Response*** Models that grabs a list of blocks to update/replace on frontend, renders their contents and put em to json reponse.

  ```
  $updated_blocks = unserialize(Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/general/update_blocks'));
  // ... for each do a $layout->getBlock('<blockName>')->toHtml() and add to json responce
  ```
- A blocks definitions taken from a core layout and from additional ajaxcart handle (layout/ajaxcart.xml). (cart_sidebar, top.links & etc.)

Comment: you have written for add product to cart

Comment: Yes, it would be similar as for "add". There is also a helper method for the deletion (or you could write your own):
$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getRemoveUrl($item)

Comment: All magic happens in setLocation(), so you need to pass the deletion url into it. Have a luck!;)

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the following code

```
<?php
$id = '100'; // replace product id with your id

$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach($items as $item):
if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $id):
$itemId = $item->getItemId();
$cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
break;
endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.yeah! I got the delete action code from core file. But i dunno, how to call this controller function by ajax!